# How can I reset a TimePicker with xaml only?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, winui

I want that  a click on a button resets the changes of a timepicker so that its hour, minute and AM/PM are unselected. I know how to do that over a click method handler, but want to know if theres a shorter way with xaml only.

I played arount with binding, but did not get it:

```xml
<TimePicker
    x:Name="ExitTime"
    Header="Exit Time"
    MinuteIncrement="1" />
<Button
    Content="Reset"
    Click="{Binding ElementName=ExitTime, Path=SelectedTime, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Why shorter? Shorter is often not better.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always need this piece of code to reset the `TimePicker`, unless you reset it from the binding target.

```cs
.SelectedTime = null;
```

If you just don't want to put this in `Page`'s code-behind:

**Option A:**

Create a `UserControl` or a custom control that has a **Reset** button and you reset the `TimerPicker` inside the it. I'd go with this way.

**Option B:**

Create a custom control:

```cs
public class TimePickerEx : TimePicker
{
    public void Reset() => SelectedTime = null;
}
```

and you can reset the `TimePicker` with XAML only like this:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="TimePickerExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TimePickerExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:TimePickerEx x:Name="ExitTime" />
        <Button Content="Reset" Click="{x:Bind ExitTime.Reset}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

<s>But you'll need to install the **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed** NuGet package, so it might not be the shorter way.</s>

Thanks to @SimonMourier tip in the comments, you don't need **Behaviors**. You can just bind the `Reset` method.

Comment: There's more simple with Option B: just declare the XAML like this: `<Button Click="{x:Bind ExitTime.Reset}" Content="Reset" />`

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks! You're right. It's way simpler this way.